# How to permanently hide soft keyboard on searchview and edittext

Tags: android, keyboard

I want to hide soft keyboard everywhere in my application permanently. So I can use my custom keyboard. I have checked many solutions but still soft keyboard is appearing. Here is my code to register searchview.

```
   EditText mEditText;
    SearchView mSearchView;
    public void registerSearchView(final SearchView sview, final MenuItem searchItem ) {
        mSearchView = sview;
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) mHostActivity.getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        mSearchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(mHostActivity.getComponentName()));
        mEditText = (EditText) mSearchView.findViewById(R.id.search_src_text);
        ImageView closeButton = (ImageView) mSearchView.findViewById(R.id.search_close_btn);
        closeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mEditText.getText() == null || mEditText.getText().length() < 1) {
                    mSearchView.onActionViewCollapsed();
                    MenuItemCompat.collapseActionView(searchItem);
                    hideCustomKeyboard();
                } else {
                    mEditText.setText("");
                    mSearchView.setQuery("", false);
                }
                //Collapse the search widget
            }
        });
        mEditText.setOnTouchListener(onTouch);
        mSearchView.setOnTouchListener(onTouch);
        mEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(oFocusChange);
        mSearchView.setOnFocusChangeListener(oFocusChange);
        mEditText.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
        mSearchView.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
        mSearchView.setOnSearchClickListener(onClickListener);


    private View.OnClickListener onClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ((InputMethodManager) mHostActivity.getSystemService(ActionBarActivity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
            showCustomKeyboard(v);
            v.clearFocus();
            v.requestFocus();

        }
    };
    private View.OnTouchListener onTouch = new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            if (mEditText.getText()==null || mEditText.getText().length() < 1){
                v.clearFocus();
                v.requestFocus();
            }
            ((InputMethodManager) mHostActivity.getSystemService(ActionBarActivity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
            v.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
            return true;
        }
    };
    private View.OnFocusChangeListener  oFocusChange = new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean b) {
            if (b == false) {
                hideCustomKeyboard();
            } else {
                ((InputMethodManager) mHostActivity.getSystemService(ActionBarActivity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
                showCustomKeyboard(v);
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: public static void hideSoftKeyboard(View view, Activity activity) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }

Comment: public static void hideKeyboard( Activity activity ) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        View f = activity.getCurrentFocus();
        if( null != f && null != f.getWindowToken() && EditText.class.isAssignableFrom( f.getClass() ) )
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow( f.getWindowToken(), 0 );
        else
            activity.getWindow().setSoftInputMode( WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN );
    }

Answer (score 1):

This will work as you can force android to hide the keyboard !!

```
public static void disableSoftInputFromAppearing(EditText editText) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
        editText.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
        editText.setTextIsSelectable(true);
    } else {
        editText.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
        editText.setFocusable(true);
    }
}
```

above code will work foresure !!

as well for search view

```
 mSearchView.clearFocus();
```

will solve the issue

Comment: But where to put it? I am using the same method to hide the keyboard and implemented it on onClick and onTouch but still keyboard is appearing over searchview.

Comment: check if it work in onPostResume , as usually in case of edittext it work in oncreate()

Comment: Keyboard appear every time when you click on a edittext or searchview. If we hide it in oncreate it will hide it just for one time but I want to hide it permanently.

Comment: I just updated my answer , use the above code it will definatly work !!
just pass all the EditText in onCreate to this method !!

Comment: @user934820 : let me know if it does not solve this issue. as for me this code work in custom keyboard scenario

Comment: It worked like a charm for edittext but not for searchview. Can you please provide me full code for searchview? And also what if I want to enable soft keyboard again for edittext. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to you manifest :

```
 <activity android:name="com.your.package.ActivityName"
      android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"  />
```

Comment: it just hide keyboard for one time. When you touch searchview or edittext keyboard appear again.

Comment: try to make the editext not clickable with addition to android:windowSoftInputMode:                                                                              android:clickable="false" 
        android:cursorVisible="false" 
        android:focusable="false" 
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"

Comment: I can use edittext.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL); but I want to use editext and searchview work normally.

Comment: do that and add touch listener to the editext, and let it request focus(or not) add listener to the keys of your keyboard, onclick on each key and the keyvalue to the edittext using ...setTextView(old value + new key), what's the problem in that ?

Comment: I do appreciate your suggestions but when user want to remove text? and when user select the text? and so on.

Comment: you can add delete key, for selection I have no idea... did you think about create custom keyboard :http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-keyboard-on-android--cms-22615

Comment: I have created a custom keyboard and I did mention it in my question that I want to use my custom keyboard instead.